# Filtering Get() in repository based on a particular attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm new to Entity Framework and was a bit confused on the filtering of the Get() method. I want to add a filter where the database will retrieve the data of only the specific attributes that I'll have to dynamically specify. Basically it will generate an expression based on a query string.

Currently I have this filter in my Get() method:

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(  
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,  
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,  
        string includeProperties = "")  
    {  
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = Entities;  

        if (filter != null)  
        {  
            query = query.Where(filter);  
        }  

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split  
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))  
        {  
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);  
        }  

        if (orderBy != null)  
        {  
            return orderBy(query).ToList();  
        }  
        else  
        {  
            return query.ToList();  
        }  
    }
```

So my Team model has 3 attributes which are:

```
    public virtual string TeamId { get; set; }
    public virtual string ChannelId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
```

So basically I want to retrieve all the data in Team Entity of a particular person using the Name attribute like this $filter=Name eq 'XYZ':

[image]

Comment: Is this method you created all by yourself or it's a override of something? Usualy DbContext classes has Find() method to look up entities by Id and if you want specific filters you should use other Linq Methods such as FirstOrdefault(), Where(), OrderBy(), Select()

Comment: And you seem to be creating a very generic method in repository layer to be called in a higher level layer such as application. I don't think it's a good idea create a method so generic like this. You could rearrange your methods in business/repository to be more like GetAll(), GetById(), GetOrdered(), GetByName() and so on. Because all queries will be focused in business layer. In way what you're doing you're transfering the responsability of queries to application layer and that can be seen as a bad design pratice

Comment: @DouglasFerreira Okay so I made a Find() method. Will this syntax help me get what I want to achieve?
public IEnumerable<TEntity> Find(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)  
        {  
            return Entities.Where(predicate);  
        }